# Coldfusion set date/time to another country

Tags: datetime, coldfusion, railo

My server is in New Zealand - clients site is Australian, How do I display the correct date and times?

Comment: JavaScript runs on the client.  Hint hint.

Comment: This could well be a way to go, @DanBracuk. It'd probably be easier than offsetting the server time thoughout the app.

Comment: I really only need to offset it in the app.cfc then use the variable.

Comment: What I meant is you've still got to *apply* the offset throughout the app. And (see comments below), that won't work reliably anyhow.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to suggest an answer that others may feel is slightly over engineered, but is probably best.

I would suggest using [JODA-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/).  With this, all you have to do is recompile it every few months with a changed public timezone database.  This means that you won't have to go through all your code and look for things like `#DateAdd('d',-10,Now())#` whenever Australia suddenly decides that they're removing/adding/changing DST or something else, instead you can write a function for JODA time that picks out the correct timezone for Australia and serves it up.  It's a little bit more legwork than doing `#DateAdd('d',-10,Now())#` but if your client suddenly moves to a different timezone in Australia or a different country, you'll be thankful.

Comment: This is a good starting point. One thing to bear in mind here is that CF date/times are actually TZ aware to a degree, so it's not just a matter of offsetting the time. For example the datetime 2014-09-28 01:30:00 exists in Sydney, but does not in Auckland (at 1am in NZ, the time jumps fwd to 2am, so 1:30am doesn't exist on that date in NZ). So if one offsets 3:30am on the NZ server to be 1:30am for display in Sydney... one will get an error. Because the offset date object is still using NZ's TZ. You will need to use JODA-Time throughout, I think.

Comment: Ok sounds good. I've download JODA, however I cannot find any info on how to install it on my Railo server :( Anyone?

Comment: @SiLlewellyn I don't use railo, but if it's like CF, what you'll have is a JAR file, so you'll need to include it in your JAR path for railo to load it which is found in the CFIDE? administrator section.

Comment: FYI, Railo also supports [dynamic loading via `createObject()`](http://blog.getrailo.com/post.cfm/railo-tip-createobject-java)